# Scrollbars disabled in my HTML/CSS? while using Progid Microsoft gradient.

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

*NOTE*: Please see the bottom of question for update!

Here is an extract (sample) of my HTML/CSS:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6699CC', endColorstr='#1C3854');
}

.container
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.box
{
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

and

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <!-- content 1 -->
    </div>
  </div><div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <!-- content 2 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This page only needs to work in IE8+ (since it is running on SOE).

When the browser is maximised and/or there is very little content, there are no scrollbars, as expected.

When the browser is small and/or there is lots of content, there are scroll bars however they are greyed out. The user is unable to scroll to stuff off the edge of the visible region.

I have tried specifying an overflow property on HTML and body but it still only gives greyed-out scroll bars.

Commenting out the height: 100% for html/body seems to fix vertical scrolling but not horizontal - however it breaks my gradient.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I was trying to put together a sample with lorem-ipsum content to show the problem for jQuerybeast, and I found that scroll was suddenly working: I was initially confused but then realised I hadn't included the background gradient (filter:progid......). As soon as I added the gradient, scroll stopped working. Why is this gradient breaking scroll?

Comment: My IE8 shows scrollbars with content. Can you please show me actual content?

Comment: @jQuerybeat: See updated question. Make sure you have put the gradient in, that is what appears to be the problem! Demo is here: http://pastebin.com/yjAN5wr9

Comment: jsfiddle is often easier to use for these kinds of examples than pastebin: http://jsfiddle.net/8AZF9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no good solution around it.

Worse yet: **progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient** is *horribly buggy* so mouse events (hover, click, scrolls etc.) are buggy. - Beware!

Regardless, you better start considering which fallbacks/workarounds/NastyHacks feel acceptable to you.

You can consider to use a gradient background image and repeat it accordingly.

Comment: As a super-hacky solution, I wrote a PHP page to return a 1px-wide .gif with a gradient using GD. The image is the height of the browser window and gets reset every time the user resizes the window. Luckily it's only going to be run on the corp intranet so bandwidth/latency is not a concern at all.

Comment: If its going to be run on the corp intranet, there are other solutions which you do not need to use PHP at all. Just make a large and use jQuery to resize it on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set the overflow after some event, something like this:

```
.gradient{ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#CCCCCC',GradientType=0 ); }

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#mydivid').position().top}, 'fast').css('overflow', 'auto');
```